# jquery recently added highlighted css can not be remove after alert generate

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/Cyjye/
I m new to jquery. I have made html table shown in jsfiddle.Firstly selection be made from second row second cell in my html table selection be made from first row second cell. I have allot time to patient not more than 30 minutes. if user selects more than 30 minutes it gives alert "Time slot not more than 30 minutes". alert works correctly but its added css is not removed after alert. and whenever I mouse up after alert .cell is highlighted with css. I don't want to do like that if alert generate then recently added css to cell is removed and whenever I mouseup after alert then no cell be highlighted with css. I tried lot but not getting correct way.
when I highlight 30 minute time and click on select patient button(below to html table there is select patient(patient getting from textbox)button) then highlight css is removed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Drag selection example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

        google.setOnLoadCallback(function ()
        {
            var active = false;
            var lastActionWasError = false;
            $('#tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(2), #tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(3)').mousedown(function (ev)
            {
                active = true;
                $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight"); // clear previous selection
                ev.preventDefault(); // this prevents text selection from happening
                $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight");
                $(".temp_selected").removeClass("temp_selected");
                $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
                $(this).addClass("temp_selected");
            });

            $('#tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(2), #tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(3)').mousemove(function (ev)
            {
                if (lastActionWasError)
                {
                    $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight");
                    $(".temp_selected").removeClass("temp_selected");
                    lastActionWasError = false;
                }
                if (active)
                {
                    $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
                    $(this).addClass("temp_selected");
                }
                if ($('.temp_selected').length > 6)
                {
                    alert("Time slot not more than 45 minutes.");
                    $(this).removeClass("csstdhighlight");
                    $(this).removeClass("temp_selected");
                    lastActionWasError = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .csstdhighlight
        {
            background-color: #ccffcc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tableAppointment" cellspacing="1" width="50%" border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                <b>Patient Name</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="70px">
                8:00AM
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                0
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                15
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                30
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                45
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                9:00AM
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                0
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                15
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                30
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                45
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jsfiddle and your explanation dont match ? I dont see  if temp_selected'.length == 7

Comment: if temp_selected'.length == 7 means if user selects more than 6 cells then inckuding recently added temp_selected.length is 7

Comment: **That is not very human readable text.** Even if one manages to read through that horribly formatted text, there are still plenty of typos to make sure that it is hard to understand anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove highlighed css from the last selected cell use

```
$(this).removeClass("csstdhighlight");
$(this).removeClass("temp_selected");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyjye/1/)

Comment: on mouse up every times alert generate after selecting time slot

Comment: @prabhat:after alert generate recently added css is gone corect but after clic 'OK' on alert and then when i mouse move then highlighted table cell is gone how should handle(persist highlighted cell after click on OK button of alert )

Comment: If you persist already selected then you will keep on getting alert message which is happening in the initial fiddle that I posted, as 6 rows are already selected and selecting 7th one will generate Alert.

Comment: in ur second fiddle  after generating alert if click 'OK' then and come again to highlighted cell the selection gone.we have to persist selection after click on button also in page how is possible in jquery prabhat.

Comment: in ur first fiddle After selecting more than 6 cells alert is generate contionously if we mouse move on table.

Comment: @prabhat : the problem is when alert generate and when click on 'OK' of alert at the same time table cell is click and is highlighted with css so length is 7 now and again alert generate and click on 'OK' of alert at the same time table cell is click and is highlighted with css. This is repeated all the time when click on 'OK' .how we get out of that

Comment: ok I think I got your question, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyjye/4/), after alert, click on cell, it wont throw you error, till you select seven rows again

Comment: i check ur fiddle  and edited my question with ur current fiddle jquery and my html.Just copy the code and paste in ur html file and run what happen when u select 7 cells then alert generates after click on OK of alert selected highlight cell is gone. and recently click cell is highlighted..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12375/discussion-between-mprabhat-and-nikhil)

Comment: Thanks prabhat if u have time tmrw then just msg